# Tensorflow/keras , GPU not used during training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Keras built in Tensorflow. 
I'm using a `conda env` with `tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0`
And i have CUDA 9.0 with cudnn 7

I see my GPU going up to 30% for few seconds at the beginning of the training (It loads images I guess). Then, it comes back to 1 or 2% while the CPU is running at 20-25%

I tried to use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` and my CPU goes up to 94% (so tensorflow is using GPU...)

Here is my model and how I train it :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras

taille_image = (96,96)      
batch_size = 32 

model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=(taille_image[0], taille_image[1], 3),padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())                
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3,activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.summary()


def Entrainer(texte, barre, nb_epochs): 


        train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True
        )
        valid_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

        test_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                directory='Images traitées/train',
                batch_size=batch_size,
                target_size=taille_image,
                color_mode="rgb",
                class_mode="categorical",
                shuffle=True,
                seed=42
        )

        validation_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                directory='Images traitées/validation',
                batch_size=1,
                target_size=taille_image,
                color_mode="rgb",
                class_mode="categorical",
                shuffle=True,
                seed=42
        )

        test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                directory='Images traitées/test',
                batch_size=1,
                target_size=taille_image,
                color_mode="rgb",
                class_mode=None,
                shuffle=False,
                seed=42
        )
        NAME = "16,32,64,128,256-conv-{}-batchs-{}".format(batch_size,int(time.time()))
        tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = 'Graph/{}'.format(NAME))
        step_size_train = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
        step_size_valid = validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size
        step_size_test = test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size

        model.fit_generator(
                generator=train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                validation_steps = step_size_valid,
                epochs=nb_epochs,
                callbacks = [tensorboard]
        )
```

It returns :

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 11085 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 2787 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 89 images belonging to 1 classes.
2019-02-07 10:18:08.258962: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2019-02-07 10:18:08.681742: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 970M major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.038
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 3.00GiB freeMemory: 2.48GiB
2019-02-07 10:18:08.686793: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-02-07 10:18:09.293895: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-02-07 10:18:09.296482: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2019-02-07 10:18:09.302927: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2019-02-07 10:18:09.306066: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2169 MB memory)
-> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
Epoch 1/16
 20/346 [>.............................] - ETA: 2:50 - loss: 0.9647 - acc: 0.5500
```

It is quite slow, and when i check the performances of my GPU :
[GPU 1% usage during training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhVSv.png)

Comment: Do you have an SSD? Since your disk is used at 100% I think you could be bound by IO. You should try a different generator that preloads images into memory.

Comment: Quick test to check whether the GPU is being used or not: define `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` as an environment variable (either in the console before opening python or via the `os.environ` dict), run again and check runtime. If it's much slower (and your CPU usage goes up), you're actually using the GPU, but not to its full potential (in which case, the most likely culprit is the input pipeline)

Comment: I have an HDD, so, do you think the learing process is limited by my HDD ?

Comment: I tried with my 1080Ti and SSD PC, and same... But during détection, my GPU is used at 15%. And SSD used at 45% (for both training and detection)

Comment: I tried the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1 and my CPU goes up to 94%